# Create static report from dynamic shiny markdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a `shiny markdown` app in which I have several figures, say for different days of the week. Above these figures is a text area where I write some comments.

I want to be able to export this report to a `static markdown` format.

I'm presenting a (mainly) reproducible example below, the first part is the code that I would like to have edited so that it creates the code from the second part in a separate file.

````
---
title: "WEEKLY REPORT"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
```

```{r header, echo=FALSE}
selectInput("x", label = "x",choices = 1:10,width="100%")
actionButton("button", "Export report")
```

## Monday

```{r monday}
textAreaInput("mon", label = NULL)
renderPlot({
plot(log(1:input$x))
})
```

## Tuesday

```{r tuesday}
textAreaInput("tue", label = NULL)
renderPlot({
plot(sin(1:input$x))
})
```
````

How can I edit it so the action button creates a new a Rmd file containing the code below (or an Rmd file that would create a similar output)? (change png urls to any existing file to make it reproducible).

```
---
#  title: "WEEKLY REPORT"
output: html_document
---

## Monday

The text I would have put on the first box

![](plot_monday.png)    

## Tuesday

The text I would have put on the second box

![](plot_tuesday.png)
```

So basically the input selectors have to go, the text areas need to be changed to standard text (possibly containing markdown), and the plots have to be exported as picture files for the relevant inputs and then inserted back as pictures in the report.

Ideally I would also like to be able to export monday and tuesday into different Rmd files.

Comment: There is a package [`webshot`](https://rdrr.io/cran/webshot/man/appshot.html) that lets you make `png` screenshots from shiny apps. You could use that by wrapping your `Rmd` document in a shiny app. See [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/859).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest is to use a report template and pass in the inputs as parameters.

So, you create a *new* report with the filename "sampleRmdReport.Rmd" in the same directory as your Shiny report with the following contents:

````
---
title: "Weekly Report"
author: "Moody_Mudskipper"
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(),"%Y-%B-%d")`'
output: html_document
params:
  mondayText: "holder"
  tuesdayText: "holder"
  x: "holder"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, results = "asis")
```
# Monday

```{r}
cat(params$mondayText)
```

```{r}
plot(log(1:params$x))
```

# Tuesday

```{r}
cat(params$tuesdayText)
```

```{r}
plot(sin(1:params$x))
```
````

Then, add the following to your Shiny report:

````
Download the weekly report:

```{r}
downloadHandler(
  filename = function(){
    paste0("weeklyReport_generated_"
           , format(Sys.Date(), "%Y%b%d")
           , ".html")
  }
  , content = function(file){
    rmarkdown::render(input = "sampleRmdReport.Rmd"
                      , output_file = file
                      , params = list(mondayText = input$mon
                                      , tuesdayText = input$tue
                                      , x = input$x
    ))
  }
  , contentType = "text/html"
)

```
````

making the full file:

````
---
title: "WEEKLY REPORT"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)



```

```{r header}
selectInput("x", label = "x",choices = 1:10,width="100%")
```

Download the weekly report:

```{r}
downloadHandler(
  filename = function(){
    paste0("weeklyReport_generated_"
           , format(Sys.Date(), "%Y%b%d")
           , ".html")
  }
  , content = function(file){
    rmarkdown::render(input = "sampleRmdReport.Rmd"
                      , output_file = file
                      , params = list(mondayText = input$mon
                                      , tuesdayText = input$tue
                                      , x = input$x
    ))
  }
  , contentType = "text/html"
)

```




## Monday

```{r monday}
textAreaInput("mon", label = NULL)

renderPlot({
  plot(log(1:input$x))
})


```


## Tuesday

```{r tuesday}
textAreaInput("tue", label = NULL)

renderPlot({
  plot(sin(1:input$x))
})
```
````

Then, clicking on the "Download" button will generate the report and prompt the user to download it. Note that if you test in RStudio, the file name won't work. I suggest opening it in the browser to test that.

Then, if you want to be able to generate separate daily reports, just add a template for the report you want and a download button for each. Or, you can make your `downloadHandler` generate a report for each day (from templates) and put them in a zipped directory to download together.

(Note: I tend to find this is more flexible in a Shiny App than in a markdown document, particularly as that allows more control of the download button. Depending on your use case, it may be worth considering that as an approach.)

Based on the comments, here is a version that would upload to Imgur and insert the images that way. Replace the other template with this or add a second button. Note that I did not make the imgur upload function work because I do not have an API key (I assume you do, since you are planning to do it this way).

````
---
title: "Weekly Report"
author: "Moody_Mudskipper"
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(),"%Y-%B-%d")`'
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: false
params:
  mondayText: "holder"
  tuesdayText: "holder"
  x: 1
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, results = "asis")
library(ggplot2)
tempDir <- tempdir()

uploadImgur <- function(fileName){
  # This function would need to upload with the Imgur API
  # I don't have a key, and don't want to set one up
  # for this example.

  # It would return the url that imgur assigns the image
  # here, I am using a placeholder
  outUrl <- "https://i.imgur.com/WsUV4DK.gif"

  return(outUrl)
}
```

# Monday

```{r}
cat(params$mondayText)
```


```{r}
tempPlot <-
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = 1:params$x
                       , y = log(1:params$x))) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("X") +
  ylab("Y")

tempFile <- tempfile("plot_", tempDir, ".png")
ggsave(tempFile, tempPlot, width = 4, height = 4)

imgurURL <- uploadImgur(tempFile)

cat("![](", imgurURL,")", sep = "")
```



# Tuesday

```{r}
cat(params$tuesdayText)
```


```{r}
tempPlot <-
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = sin(1:params$x)
                       , y = log(1:params$x))) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("X") +
  ylab("Y")

tempFile <- tempfile("plot_", tempDir, ".png")
ggsave(tempFile, tempPlot, width = 4, height = 4)

imgurURL <- uploadImgur(tempFile)

cat("![](", imgurURL,")", sep = "")

```
````

Comment: I like the approach, and it could be satisfying for some cases, but there are a few issues.

Comment: **First** it gives me html and not markdown files as output which means I have to build templates when the structure was all laid out in thedynamic report already. That's acceptable as I won't build very complex reports but it's still additional time and risk for mistakes and debugging. I think it can be handled with some parsing of dynamic report and a fair bit of regex fun though.

Comment: **Second issue** is that it renders with plots and not pictures. To be transparent I'd like to use the `wordpress` package to blog from R, using a function named `knit2wp` and it doesn't work with plots (so for this use i'll have to plug in a step to upload pngs to imgur as well and use this url, but it's another issue). @Nice posted a solution with `ggsave` that I think could be mixed with your approach, though he deleted it fast for some reason.

Comment: I hear you, and if it doesn't work, it doesn't work. To your first concern, however, I think that building a separate template may actually be better. It gives flexibility to build something slightly different (if you want it) and it means you don't have to be as locked-in to the Shiny report format (e.g., if you wanted to switch to an app to get a tab or side panel or add dynamic sectioning to the report, etc.). To the second, you may be able to add the imgur steps to your template. E.g., use ggsave, upload to imgur, then use `cat` to dynamically add the url (instead of a plot) to the report.

Comment: both very good points, I guess I could save pics, upload them, render them through url and blog the whole thing in one step if I replace your `downloadHandler` with the right code.

Comment: I just added a template that does the Imgur upload as a part of the template. It will require some programming work to do the Imgur step, but it addresses the embeded-vs-uploaded image question.

Comment: It looks like this package: https://github.com/astatham/imgur-R-Package may have already built most of the uploading functionality that you need. Hope this ends up working for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using `ggplot` you can use `ggsave` to save the plots locally as png.

You could try this for your main file:

````
---
title: "WEEKLY REPORT"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r header, echo=FALSE}
selectInput("x", label = "x",choices = 1:10,width="100%")
actionButton("button", "Export report")
observeEvent(input$button,{
  params <- list(text = input$mon)
  render('report.Rmd',params = params)
})
```

## Monday

```{r monday}
textAreaInput("mon", label = NULL)
renderPlot({
  p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=1:input$x,y=log(1:input$x)),aes(x=x,y=y))+
    geom_point()   
  ggsave("plot.png",plot=p)
  p
})
```
````

And for your static report (needs to be in the same folder as the other .Rmd):

````
---
#  title: "WEEKLY REPORT"
output: html_document
---

## Monday
```{r}
params$text
```

![plot](plot.png)
````

I'm not sure how to make a proper download button with a download handler in a shiny Rmd so this only works when run from RStudio and not in a browser.